# Why interaction is the same while main effect changes after adjusting for covariates?

Tags: r, mixed-model, interaction, confounding

Hi I am confused by a result from my analysis.

I have two linear mixed models, the data was from a family-based study. The dependent variable is V1 (continuous), and the independent variables are V2 (continuous), V3 (continuous), and several covariates (some are continuous, some are categorical).

```
Model 1: V1 = V2 + V3 + V2*V3 

Model 2: V1 = V2 + V3 + V2*V3 + covariates
```

The result from model 1 shows V2 (coefficient: 0.01, p-value: 0.001) and V2*V3 (coefficient: 0.002, p-value: 0.001) are significant. However, the result from model 2 shows V2 is non-significant (coefficient: 0.006, p-value: 0.10), but V2*V3 is still the same (coefficient: 0.002, p-value: 0.001). Is this situation possible? How can I interpret it?

I also checked my R code for the models. The code for models is as below:

```
lmer(V1 ~ V2 + V3 + V2*V3 + covariates + (1|family), data=mydata)
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: BTW, V3 does not change too much, it is non-significant in both Model 1 and Model 2. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Coefficients change when variables correlated with the predictors enter the model. Yoru results indicate that the interaction is not correlated with the predictors conditional on the other variables in the model. This would be especially plausible if the terms in the interaction were centered at their means. It doesn't really indicate anything statistically or substantively interesting, though. You probably shouldn't be interpreting the "main effects" of a regression with an interaction anyway (because they correspond to the slope of the variable when the other variable in the interaction is held at zero, which is usually not a meaningful value unless the terms are centered).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! So the "significant" interaction here is not meaningful? Do I need to center the interaction term and run the model again? Also, I still do not understand why V2 changes dramatically while V3 and V2*V3 do not change. Thank you again for your kind help!

Comment: The significant interaction is meaningful. The fact that it doesn't change when you add another predictor is not meaningful. You should almost always center variables you include in an interaction if you want to interpret the main effect terms. V2 is probably correlated with the covariates whereas V3 and the interaction are not.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, just two last questions : )   1. There does exist an interaction between V2 and V3 on V1, right? 2. How could the interaction term do not correlate with the covariates when it include V2? Thank you so much for your time and help! Hope you have a great day.

Comment: Try running the following R: `a <- rnorm(1e3); b <- a + rnorm(1e3,0,sqrt(.3)); c <- rnorm(1e3); cor(cbind(a,b,c,b_c = b*c))`. You'll see that even though `a` and `b` are highly correlated, `a` and `b*c` are not correlated. It can just happen. Test it out with your data.